# Why does my regular expression work in string.replace(), but not in RegExp()? In javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

When running my replace statement using a regular expression not defined by the regex object it returns the correct result

```js
var str = "from |cffa22fc8Peachee|r others";
var res = str.replace(/\|cffa22fc8Peachee\|r/gi, "red");
        
console.log(res);
//> from red others
```

However when it is executed using the regex object *(which i need to be able to use)* The result is different, even though i escaped the special characters.

```js
var str = "from |cffa22fc8Peachee|r others";
var regex = new RegExp("/\|cffa22fc8Peachee\|r/", "gi");
var res = str.replace(regex, "red");

console.log(res)
//> from |red|r others
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My guess is that maybe this expression is what you wish to write:

```
\|[^|]*\|\S*
```

#### Test

```js
const regex = /\|[^|]*\|\S*/g;
const str = `from |cffa22fc8Peachee|r others`;
const subst = `red`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/M1k0SA/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/M1k0SA/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

When creating a `RegExp()` you should *omit* the quotation marks, as they're *already* part of `str`. Instead of `"/\|cffa22fc8Peachee\|r/"`, you're looking for `/\|cffa22fc8Peachee\|r/`:

```js
var str = "from |cffa22fc8Peachee|r others";
var regex = new RegExp(/\|cffa22fc8Peachee\|r/, "gi");
var res = str.replace(regex, "red");

console.log(res)
```